# What is the difference between git push -u?

Tags: git, git-push

On GitHub, they advice to do git push -u origin master, instead of git push.

What is the main difference ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man git-push`:

> ```
>    -u, --set-upstream
>       For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add
>       upstream (tracking) reference ...
> ```

Basically, it means that it will not only upload your `master` to the `master` at `origin`, but also set up the local copy `origin/master` to be the tracking branch, that is the *upstream* of your local `master`.

This is usually already this way, so if that is the case, being in `master` and doing `git push -u origin master` will do nothing different from a plain `git push`. But if you misconfigured your repository, then sometimes the long version will fix it automatically.

Naturally, doing that command without thinking may result in bad situations, for example if you are in a public working branch and do that:

```
{mybranch} $ git push -u origin master
```

Now you uploaded your `mybranch` as `master` and set up `origin/master` as the *upstream* of `mybranch`, instead of the proper `origin/mybranch`, and you created quite a mess!

My guess is that GitHub recommends that for git newbies, to avoid calls to their customer support. But I would not recommend that as a default for pushing. In fact, if you misconfigure the upstream, a plain `git push` will fail with this message:

```
fatal: The current branch a has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

that tells you exactly what is happening and how to fix it (`--set-upstream` is a synonym of `-u`).

Comment: I  believed that `git push -u origin master` would have set `mybranch` upstream to `origin/master` but that doesn't seem to be the case in my test.  Hence my question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784411/what-does-git-push-u-origin-branch-do-when-you-are-not-on-branch